# Node-React always returns 500 instead of custom errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I'm having troubles returning errors on my server. when running on localhost - everything works fine, custom errors are returning great to the client. After deploying to a host (Heroku, Render etc...) the valid requests are working as expected, but when error is occuring - Im receiving 500 instead of the custom error I'd like to return.

Tried several error handlers and no work.

ERROR HANDLER (SERVER)

```
const errorHandler = (error, request, response, next) => {
    console.log(error);
    if (error.errorType !== undefined && error.errorType.isShowStackTrace){
        response.status(error.errorType.httpCode).json({message: error.errorType.message});
        return;
    }
    
    response.status(700).json({message: 'GENERAL ERROR OCCURED'});
}

module.exports = errorHandler;
```

REQUEST (CLIENT)

```
        try{
            const response = await axios.post("https://myUrl.com/users/login", user);
            localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
            return response.data;
        }
        catch (err : any){
            return err;
        }
```

Expected custom error, and got 500

Comment: What if you send an actual error code like 501?

Comment: Are you sure it's not going inside the `if` and returning the error code based on `error.errorType.httpCode`

Comment: @Samathingamajig
Hey, thanks for your reply!

I tried returning custom codes like 600, 601, 602 .....
I tried it in several ways, most of them are something like
response.status(600).json({message: 'TESTTESTTEST'});
All of these getting 500 for some reason, BTW I'm getting the same result when trying to do it from postman.

THE WEIRD THING - 501 works well though for some reason.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Whatever library you're using for requests, or possibly heroku, seems to not support custom error codes (i.e. not on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Comment: @Samathingamajig
Yes, I tried mocking something like 
response.status(600).json({message: error.errorType.message});
got 500.

Can't I use custom error codes?

Comment: you really shouldn't be sending custom error status codes, you should be sending standard error codes with custom status messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All valid HTTP status codes are [within the range of 100 to 599, inclusive](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc9110.html#rfc.section.15).

The rfc9110 spec makes it clear that these are extensible, but only provided that you follow the rule above (emphasis added):

> HTTP status codes are extensible. A client is not required to understand the meaning of all registered status codes, though such understanding is obviously desirable. **However, a client MUST understand the class of any status code, as indicated by the first digit, and treat an unrecognized status code as being equivalent to the x00 status code of that class.**

In other words, systems need to know that you're sending a Server error, indicated by the fact that it starts with a `5` or a Client error that would start with a `4`.

Comment: Thank you, and thanks to @Samathingamajig
Understood, solved the problem! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Im no expert in node but is that middleware? Try calling next()

Comment: Yes, "next()" will pass to the next middleware.
In my case - from where the error was thrown -> to the error handler.